# ¿Cómo importar datos de archivo xlsx a MySQL con PHP sin que se repitan registros?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy haciendo la importación de un archivo `.xlsx` a mi base de datos en MySQL con PHP. Todo funciona muy bien pero al momento de volver a subir el archivo me duplica los registros.

Me gustaría si me pueden apoyar con esto ya que ese archivo lo modifican pero no borran los registros anteriores.

Dejo mi código. Por cierto, uso la librería `simplexlsx`.

**creacion.php**

```
<?php
//Incluyo la clase
include 'simplexlsx.class.php';
$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX( 'countries_and_population.xlsx' );//Instancio la clase y le paso como parametro el archivo a leer
$fp = fopen( 'datos.csv', 'w');//Abrire un archivo "datos.csv", sino existe se creara
foreach( $xlsx->rows() as $fields ) {//Itero la hoja de calculo
        fputcsv( $fp, $fields);//Doy formato CSV a una línea y le escribo los datos
}
fclose($fp);//Cierro el archivo "datos.csv"
?>
```

**subir.php**

```
    <?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_name="netapp";
$db_user="root";
$db_pass="";
    include 'simplexlsx.class.php';
    $xlsx = new SimpleXLSX( 'countries_and_population.xlsx' );
    try {
       $conn = new PDO( "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", "$db_user", "$db_pass");
       $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( "INSERT INTO countries_and_population (estado, ciudad, poblacion, numRegion, dato_estimado, sociedad) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindParam( 1, $estado);
    $stmt->bindParam( 2, $ciudad);
    $stmt->bindParam( 3, $poblacion);
        $stmt->bindParam( 3, $numRegion);
    $stmt->bindParam( 4, $dato_estimado);
    $stmt->bindParam( 5, $sociedad);
    foreach ($xlsx->rows() as $fields)
    {
        $estado = $fields[0];
        $ciudad = $fields[1];
        $poblacion = $fields[2];
                $numRegion = $fields[3];
        $dato_estimado = $fields[4];
        $sociedad = $fields[5];
        $stmt->execute();
    }

?>
```

**DB**

```
CREATE TABLE `countries_and_population` (
  `estado` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `ciudad` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `numRegion` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `poblacion` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `dato_estimado` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `sociedad` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=260 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Si los registros se duplican creo que debes resolver el problema sobre todo a nivel de la base de datos, poniendo una restricción `UNIQUE` en la tabla. En dicha restricción indicarás aquellas columnas que no deberían tener más de una fila con los mismos valores. Eso sería lo primero. Luego, a la hora de la inserción puedes preguntar si existe una registro con los valores que definen tu restricción `UNIQUE`  y proceder en consecuencia.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la clave primaria? Es decir, ¿qué decide que un registro esté duplicado?

Comment: @OscarGarcia segun yo con el id podria seer el identificador para que no se duplique pero nooo por que es solamente un numero entonces cree otro registro que le asigno un numero como que de region para que ese sea el identificador de los datos para que no se dupliquen si el numero de region se duplica quiere decir que ese estado y ciudad ya existe.... $numRegion = $fields[3];

Comment: Por favor, ¿podrías compartir el esquema (o DDL) de la tabla? Usa `SHOW CREATE TABLE countries_and_population`.

Comment: estado        | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL 
ciudad        | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL
numRegion     | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL 
poblacion     | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL
dato_estimado | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL
sociedad      | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL
id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
@OscarGarcia

Comment: Por favor, agrégalo en tu pregunta al final, editándola. Y, a ser posible, la definición exacta tal y como te la devuelve la consulta que te dije y no una aproximación representada esquemáticamente.

Comment: @OscarGarcia listo ;)

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza. Entonces, según deduzco de tu mensaje anterior, la clave candidata es el agrupamiento de estado y ciudad. ¿Me equivoco? Si el `id` es autoincrementado (un recurso "fácil" para tener clave primaria, pero no es siempre necesario) y no tiene relación con el archivo excel, entonces él no debería ser clave primaria (aunque es requisito para ser autoincrementado). Tendrías que decidir si eliminar el `id` para poner la clave primaria correcta o bien mantener `id` como está y agregar una clave única con la clave candidata formada por estado y ciudad.

Comment: ¿Has podido ver la respuesta? ¿Tienes alguna duda? ¿Hay algo que cambie o que haya entendido mal? Espero tu respuesta.

Comment: disculpa @OscarGarcia he andado ocupado reordenando todo ya que me cambiaron el funcionamiento y he estado ordenando cuestiones de diseño y para implementar mas facil las nuevas funciones, si me sirvio muchas gracias utilice insert con ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE se me hico mejor su funcionamiento lo adapte y me parece mejor este muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, un placer ser de ayuda. No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta y, si lo consideras oportuno, votarla positivamente.

Comment: muchisimas gracias @OscarGarcia como siempre muy amable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es definir correctamente una clave primaria para tu tabla o, en caso de querer un identificador autonumérico (que no es necesario en la gran mayoría de los casos), definir una clave única.

Si, tal y como hemos hablado en los comentarios, los campos que forman la clave son `estado` y `ciudad`, puedes agregar la clave única (sin perder datos existentes en la tabla) de la siguiente manera:

```
ALTER TABLE countries_and_population
  ADD UNIQUE(estado, ciudad)
```

Una vez que hagas eso podrás hacer uso de dos extensiones SQL que te ofrece MySQL para hacer el trabajo:

- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)
- [REPLACE ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html)

El primero trata de insertar el dato y si éste falla por duplicidad de clave, entonces procede a actualizar el registro existente con los datos proporcionados.

El segundo trata de insertar el dato y si éste falla por duplicidad, elimina el viejo e inserta uno nuevo. Como efecto secundario, el campo `id`, que es autonumérico, se verá afectado/modificado.

Te he dejado una prueba de concepto de ambas soluciones en el siguiente [ejemplo en línea](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vw6kceQf3RFFRN6Xe3cyza/0).

Usando `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`:

```
INSERT INTO countries_and_population (
  estado, ciudad, numRegion, poblacion, dato_estimado, sociedad
) VALUES (
  'Estado1', 'Ciudad1', '5', 'Poblacion', 'Segundo insert', 'Sociedad'
), (
  'Estado1', 'Ciudad2', '5', 'Poblacion', 'Segundo insert', 'Sociedad'
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  numRegion = VALUES(numRegion),
  poblacion = VALUES(poblacion),
  dato_estimado = VALUES(dato_estimado),
  sociedad = VALUES(sociedad)
```

Usando `REPLACE`:

```
REPLACE INTO countries_and_population (
  estado, ciudad, numRegion, poblacion, dato_estimado, sociedad
) VALUES (
  'Estado1', 'Ciudad2', '5', 'Poblacion', 'Usando replace', 'Sociedad'
), (
  'Estado2', 'Ciudad1', '5', 'Poblacion', 'Usando replace', 'Sociedad'
)
```

En el ejemplo en línea podrás comprobar cómo en el primer caso (`INSERT`) el campo `id` se ve inalterado cuando se actualiza un registro existente, pero en el segundo (`REPLACE`) caso el campo `id` se regenera.

Hacer uso de `REPLACE` es más sencillo porque basta con cambiar `INSERT` por `REPLACE` en tu consulta SQL, pero tendrás el problema de la regeneración del campo autonumérico.

Tu PHP quedaría (con `REPLACE`) de la siguiente manera:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('
  REPLACE INTO countries_and_population (
    estado, ciudad, poblacion, numRegion, dato_estimado, sociedad
  ) VALUES (
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
  )
');
```